# Classifying complete extensions of a theory with countable atomic (prime) models

Tags: logic, reference-request, model-theory

I am looking for results in the literature of the form "for a first-order theory $T$, the countable atomic models of $T$ are exactly these."

This might  be a strange question to ask.  But for instance if $T$ is the theory of graphs, we have a classification of a (perhaps vastly) smaller class of atomic models: ultrahomogeneous ones.  In other words, I am interested in the generalization of the oft-studied problem.

Of course, if all complete extensions of $T$ are easily classifiable, then my problem is probably easy.  I am more interested in the case where $T$ has many complete extensions.

Comment: Take the theory of algebraically closed field (of any characteristic). The prime models are easily classified.

Comment: So are you interested in the case when $T$ has continuum-many complete extensions, but only a countably many of them have prime models?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Yes, that would be among things that I'm interesting in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to restrict your question to rule out "nuisances" as following theory.

The language contains the relation $<$ and countably many constants $c_i\le c_{i+1}$.

$T$ says that $c_0$ is the least element and for every $i\neq j$

1. $c_i=c_{i+1}\to (<$ is a discrete linear order and $c_{j+1}$ is the immediate successor of $c_j$).
2. $\exists x\in(c_i,c_{i+1})\to\ \ <$ is a dense linear order in $(c_i,c_{i+1})$

There are countably many ways for $T$ to be a discrete linear order with obvious prime models.

There are uncontably many ways for $T$ to contain some intervals $[c_i,c_{i+1}]$ that are dense (and this prevents the existence of prime models).